# Internal keyboard randomly stops working (after upgrade to Catalina) - any way to reset it?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, hardware, bug, catalina

**Is there anything like a reset of the internal keyboard device that I can try doing instead of having to restart my MacBook completely?**

- The internal keyboard on my MacBook Pro just stops responding to key presses at a random moment (and stays like that). After restarting, it works again.
- it happened 7-8 times already, every time in the middle of typing
  something. It also happened twice while I was typing this question.
- Trackpad continues to work normally.
- It happened while I had an external keyboard connected, as well. Actually, two of them, both Apple keyboards -- one wireless and the other USB. Both of them, and the internal keyboard, stopped working at that point. When I re-connected a keyboard, it continued working again (only the reconnected one).

Comment: Have you tried an SMC reset?

Comment: Just did it now (NVRAM/PRAM as well just in case), thank you. Let's see if it will happen again now.

Comment: If it doesn't happen after a few days let me know and I'll add it as an answer for you.

Comment: It just happened again now. 

Comment: Hello, i'm having exactly the same issue after catalina update :( have no solution but it's good to see that i'm not alone and this is something clearly related to Catalina and not any hardware issue

Comment: @Patroy I realised it had something to do with ***Caps Lock***, at least in my case. Funny, I know, I'm still not completely convinced, but I saw that every time the keyboard stopped working, it was when the Caps Lock was on. So I just disabled Caps Lock to see if that's the issue (by going to `System Preferences` > `Keyboard` > `Modifier Keys...` and setting `Caps Lock` to `No Action`) and it hasn't happened since.

Comment: @Patroy Just out of curiosity, do you happen to use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) perhaps, as I do? Not sure if it might actually be something with Karabiner

Comment: @Bloke yes, i also noticed that this happens when I’m using caps lock and also i’M using carabinier just for remapping eject key on magic keyboard ;) so if it’s karabiner related we should look forward for update of this app

Comment: Well, disabling Caps Lock definitely fixed this for me. But whether it's a Karabiner issue or not, I'm not sure, we'd need to test that. If you don't mind quitting Karabiner (I do :D I rely on it heavily) and using your Mac without it for some sufficiently long time, you can check if the issue will happen again. If it doesn't, then it really is a Karabiner issue and you can post an answer here :)

Comment: From reading the comments, there appears to be some 3rd party software/hacks being employed here. Start by booting into Safe mode and see if the problem persists.

Comment: This appears to be the same problem as https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372578/macbook-pro-keyboard-randomly-freezes-after-upgrading-to-catalina . (And yes, I'm having it too, and I use Karabiner, and this definitely has something to do with Caps Lock in my case as well.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This appears to be a Karabiner bug](https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/issues/2089#issuecomment-585890920) (at least in my case).

Comment: Did you successfully work around it? I use Karabiner too but quitting and/or restarting that app doesn’t change the system and I still need to reboot. Also, this probable  NEVER happens using an external keyboard but will happen several times an hour using the the built in keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of **workarounds** in the form of an answer so people can find them easily, since this [Karabiner bug](https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/issues/2089#issuecomment-585890920) is still bugging us actively:

### 1. Disable Caps Lock key (so it doesn't happen)

> MacOS `System Preferences` > `Keyboard` > `Modifier Keys...` and here set `Caps Lock` to `No Action`

One easy workaround is to simply disable the Caps Lock key entirely, if that is an acceptable option for you.
If you have to yell around the Internets a lot, try the next one:

### 2. Kill karabiner process (when it happens)

> In Terminal: `sudo pkill -f karabiner`

This seems to be enough for some people to get their keyboard working again without having to restart, but some say it does not work for them.

If you don't have an external keyboard to connect to type this out, or if you don't already have this command copied somewhere to simply paste it into the Terminal, you can use the "[Keyboard Viewer](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp1015/10.15/mac/10.15)":

> Click the Input menu in the menu bar, then choose **Show Keyboard Viewer**.

<sub><sup>Credits to *Jyosua* and *iwill (Mr. Ming)* from the [Github Issue page](https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements/issues/2089) for the second workaround</sup></sub>