# Macbook pro keyboard randomly freezes after upgrading to Catalina

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, performance, catalina

I am using a Macbook pro 13" with touchbar late 2016. Before upgrading to Catalina, everything works fine. After the upgrade, the internal keyboard will randomly freeze while typing (no response, caps lock light won't change). The trackpad and touchbar still works after the keyboard freezes. Pressing Fn will still change the touchbar. External keyboard works if plugged in after the internal one freezes. The   only way to unfreeze the keyboard seems to be restarting (also the only way to dim out the capslock light). I have tried reset NVRAM and SMC, but the problem is still there.

Comment: Do you have any additional settings installed? Like Logitech setting, Wacom, etc.? I'd start with removing those.

Comment: This appears to be the same problem as https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372554/internal-keyboard-randomly-stops-working-after-upgrade-to-catalina-any-way-t

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain what i'm having, I'm Macbook pro early 2015 user, and i updated to macOS Catalina 5 days ago, on the first day the keyboard was working fine, but they keyboard started freezing at random times (Only the power key works, others don't work).

So later i resetted the PRAM, SMC, NVRAM and it doesn't solve anything.

So i decided to downgrade to macOS Mojave, after downgrading the issue still continue as i was faced in the catalina also.
Then i decided to replug the battery and i did that also along with re plugging the track pad flex connector. but nothing is fixed.

Later i was digging for a solution for this issue over the internet. I found that there is a common issue with the 2015 models, and the touchpad flex is causing this issue, and after replacing it will get rid of this issue, so i decided to go with replacing it.

If you like you can downgrade to Mojave and recheck the issue still continues incase you want to be sure. I've posted this issue on multiple forums, and if theres a fix ill inform you for sure.

Thanks,